# Method gets called two times

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsurlconnection

I am doing a NSURLConnection that downloads a file only if there is a new one (checked with the last-modified date). But to accomplish this I am using two methods with two different NSURLRequests and NSURLConnection. Well, they do the same.

```
    - (IBAction)uppdatera:(id)sender
{
    checkHeaders = YES;

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.forellgatan.se/site/ftp_files/Kapareskolan.zip"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) 
    {
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } 

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *connectFailMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ingen internetanslutning! 1" message:@"Anslut dig till internet för att ladda ner!"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [connectFailMessage show];
        [connectFailMessage release];        
    }
}

- (void)downloadNewFile
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.forellgatan.se/site/ftp_files/Kapareskolan.zip"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection2) 
    {
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } 

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *connectFailMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ingen internetanslutning! 2" message:@"Anslut dig till internet för att ladda ner!"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [connectFailMessage show];
        [connectFailMessage release];        
    }

    checkHeaders = NO;

    self.progressView.hidden = NO;
}
```

It goes through the didReceiveResponse method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if (checkHeaders == YES)
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *test = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

        if ([test respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)])
        {
            NSDictionary *metaData = [test allHeaderFields];

            NSString *lastModifiedString = [metaData objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];

            NSString *savedString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"LastModified"];

            if (![lastModifiedString isEqualToString:savedString])
            {
                [self downloadNewFile];
            }

            else if ([lastModifiedString isEqualToString:savedString])
            {       
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ingen uppdatering tillgänglig" message:@"Det finns ingen uppdatering att hämta just nu." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }

            NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [standardUserDefaults setObject:lastModifiedString forKey:@"LastModified"];
            [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
        }
    }

    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
    self.fileSize = [[NSNumber numberWithLong: [response expectedContentLength]] retain];
}
```

Last the connectionDidFinishLaunching method:

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (checkHeaders == NO)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
        [self.receivedData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Kapareskolan.zip"] atomically:YES];

        [self unzipDownloadedFile];

        self.progressView.hidden = YES;

        NSLog(@"Finished...");
    }

    [connection cancel];
}
```

I know the didFinishLaunching method gets called twice, but I want to know how I could get so the method doesn't get called twice if there is an update?

I know it's a lot asked and much code here but just give me a hint and I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're done with the first connection object in the didReceiveResponse method you should cancel it then. Otherwise it's going to make it to the connectionDidFinishLoading method.
I think this is what you want:

```
if (![lastModifiedString isEqualToString:savedString])
  {
    [connection cancel];
    [self downloadNewFile];
  }
```

Also It looks like you're setting checkHeaders to NO after you start the second request which could cause a race condition.

Comment: Thanks, should I do the NSURLConnection *theConnection2 a instance variable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking there... Can you clarify?

Comment: My bad, where should I put the `[connection cancel];` method?

Comment: Right before you call `downloadNewFile`. I've modified my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you! Have been struggling with this for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html), a connection "can be canceled any time before the delegate receives a connectionDidFinishLoading: or connection:didFailWithError: message by sending the connection a cancel message".

so why not try moving

```
      [connection cancel];
```

from the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method to just after your `if-else` block in the `didReceiveResponse` delegate method?  You want to cancel the "checkHeaders==YES" connection in either case; either you're about to kick off a new connection, or you already know all you need to know about the current connection.

UPDATED as requested:

```
  if (![lastModifiedString isEqualToString:savedString]) {
      [self downloadNewFile];
  } else { // you've already implicitly checked for equality above
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ingen uppdatering tillgänglig" message:@"Det finns ingen uppdatering att hämta just nu." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
  }
  // you've used the connection for everything that you need, so cancel it in either case
  [connection cancel];
```

as `downloadNewFile` kicks off its `NSURLConnection` asynchronously, this should be okay in the event that the two strings are equal.  Slightly safer would be to move the `cancel` method call to just prior to the `if-else` check.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm just stupid but I don't quite understand if this works. Can you put it into the code please.